# High-performance proof assistants

Tags: high-performance-computing, lean

I mainly work in the field of high-performance computing (HPC). [For a 2020 paper I did a Monte Carlo calculation using 24800 CPUs](https://aip.scitation.org/doi/full/10.1063/5.0005754), and one part of the paper was about showing that even up to 24800 CPUs, the speed of the calculation still roughly doubles when doubling the number of CPUs. To reach 24800 CPUs I had to use hundreds of compute nodes, with each node having 40 CPUs.

**I was therefore curious about the possible existence of "high-performance" proof assistants.**

When I did a literature search, I did find some papers about parallel implementations that run on several cores (CPUs) but nothing at a scale that I'd call large. Before this site went live, I asked about this in the Proof Assistants Chatroom on MathOverflow, and [Huỳnh Trần Khanh told me](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/59821021#59821021) that the proof assistant Lean does spawn multiple threads to do the calculations required to check proof correctness, but [only uses shared memory parallelism](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/59832628#59832628) meaning that it can run on multiple CPUs but not multiple nodes. .

***I wonder if there's any proof assistant software that can be run on not only mutliple cores of a single node, but also on multiple cores spread across multiple nodes?***

Comment: Andras Kovacs did some cool research on elaboration performance of proof assistants.

Comment: At least for type-based proof assistants, as far as I know, typechecking doesn't parallelize very well, so usually effort there is spent on reducing the amount of work to be done by pruning branches, strategically delaying computations and so forth

Comment: There's ACL2(p) which is works with parallelization

Comment: @Couchy Lean does too, but only for multi-core parallelization on a single node. Can ACL2(p) parallelize over more than one node?

Comment: @ice1000 and who is best?

Comment: For high-performance elaboration, I second the recommendation of Kovacs' work (see [smalltt](https://github.com/AndrasKovacs/smalltt)). It's not really a proof assistant, but [Metamath Zero](https://github.com/digama0/mm0) might be interesting to check out as well. I don't think these don't tackle the issue of parallelism however.

Comment: Any reason you have not given an accept vote?

Comment: @GuyCoder I need more time to gi through the answers properly!

Answer (score 15):

We have to distinguish two kinds of concurrency here:

1. Concurrency when checking a single proof object, implemented within the proof assistant, as supported by e.g. Coq and Lean.
2. Concurrency while checking an entire development (over tens, hundreds, or thousands of file), implemented in the build system.

#### For the first one (single-proof concurrency)

It's not common (yet?) to run gigantic calculations within proof assistants like Coq or Lean, so concurrency at the scale that you're looking for hasn't been looked at too deeply for checking single terms.  When people want to perform huge computations with a proof assistant, they tend to write code that performs the computations they want, verify it, and then extract it and run it separately from the proof assistant, rather than relying on or performance features of and concurrency within the proof assistant.

That being said, many typechecking problems (on fully type-inferred terms, at least, which is what dependent-type-based proofs are) have a recursive structure that decomposes nicely and hence could be parallelized or distributed.  For this to work well, though, you'd want to also parallelize computation itself, because the slow part of typechecking in dependently typed proof assistants tends to be computations (often coming from reflective proofs, e.g. typechecking `eq_refl: some_large_calculation = true`).  Luckily, reduction of pure terms also decomposes nicely, and there you have a lot of previous work to look at: the problem of distributing the evaluation of a purely functional program is basically as old as functional programming itself ([example from 1985](https://nyuscholars.nyu.edu/en/publications/efficient-distributed-evaluation-of-functional-programs-using-ser))

#### For the second one (whole-development concurrency)

A more common source of concurrency in proof developments is build-time concurrency (compiling/checking multiple files in parallel).  Here, the amount of available concurrency is the width of the dependency tree (the wider the tree, the more you can parallelize the proof-checking process), as well as the quality of the build system.  I'm not aware of efforts to integrate Coq with a build system that supports distributed builds, but there's no deep reason why it wouldn't work.  I don't know about other PAs.

Answer (score 9):

Rolling with Clément's distinction of concurrency, there is a third one:

3. Concurrency when doing proof search and/or finding counter examples.

Isabelle supports all three kinds of concurrency. However, and this is why this answer might not be satisfying for you, all these are almost embarrassing parallelism only:

- (1) is solved by realization that proofs are basically irrelevant, we only care that the certification succeeds at some point (which can be later in time). [1]
- (2) is solved by exploiting the DAG structure of a theory, checking independent theories in parallel. [1]
- (3) The tools `sledgehammer` (and `try0`) and `nitpick`, described in [2] and [3] respectively, leverage some forms of concurrency. The former will check different provers (CVC4, Vampire, z3 etc.) in parallel and reports which have succeeded. It can also make use of remote solvers SystemOnTPTP web service, you might find interesting techniques for some of those servers (I don't know enough to comment on that).

---

<sup>1: [Parallel Proof Checking in Isabelle/Isar](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.149.4361) by Makarius Wenzel</sup>

<sup>2: [Hammering Away: A User’s Guide to Sledgehammer for Isabelle/HOL](https://isabelle.in.tum.de/doc/sledgehammer.pdf) by Jasmin Blanchette et al.</sup>

<sup>3: [Picking Nits: A User’s Guide to Nitpick for Isabelle/HOL](https://isabelle.in.tum.de/doc/nitpick.pdf) by Jasmin Blanchette</sup>